# STSDev not adding files to manifest.xml

Tags: sharepoint, deployment

I am using STSDev to build a Sharepoint solution package. I created the project using the STSDev "Feature with assembly" template.  I have added additional features to the project that I would like included in the solution.

My problem is that STSDev is not adding the files for the additional features to the manifest.xml file and as a result they are not being deployed.  I do see them in the generated .ddf file.

To boot, when I try to add the files manually to the manifest.xml, STSDev removes them when I rebuild.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing.  How can I force STSDev to see my files?

Answer (score 1):

STSDev regenerates manifest.xml and the DDF on each build, so adding them by hand won't help. It should automatically pick up any features in RootFiles\TEMPLATE\FEATURES. Could you maybe post the line with the feature.xml from the DDF?

Also, what version of STSDev are you using?